# Filter gridview Using Search View

Tags: android, android-cardview

I have `gridview` with text And `ImageView` and I want to add search Functionalty to it but I dont know how to do that my question say that is there any way to use search view with `gridview` ?
And here is my `gridview` adapter

```
public class GridViewWordAdapter extends   BaseAdapter {

private ImageLoader imageLoader;
private Context context;
private List<Word> movieItems;
LayoutInflater inflater;

public GridViewWordAdapter(Context context, List<Word> movieItems) {
    this.context = context;
    this.movieItems = movieItems;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return movieItems.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return movieItems.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

static class ViewHolderItem {

    TextView textViewItem;
    TextView textViewen;
    TextView textViewar;
    TextView textViewtag;
    TextView textViewaudio;
    NetworkImageView networkImageView;
}


@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View gridViewAndroid;

    if (convertView == null) {
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        gridViewAndroid = inflater.inflate(R.layout.gridview_word_layout, null);
    } else {
        gridViewAndroid = (View) convertView;
    }

    TextView textViewen = (TextView) gridViewAndroid.findViewById(R.id.tv_word_en);
    TextView textViewar = (TextView) gridViewAndroid.findViewById(R.id.tv_word_ar);
    TextView textViewtag = (TextView) gridViewAndroid.findViewById(R.id.tv_word_tagoi);
    TextView textViewaudio = (TextView) gridViewAndroid.findViewById(R.id.tv_audio);
    NetworkImageView networkImageView = (NetworkImageView) gridViewAndroid.findViewById(R.id.android_gridview_word_image);

    Word word = movieItems.get(position);

    imageLoader = CustomVolleyRequest.getInstance(context).getImageLoader();
    imageLoader.get(word.getImg(), ImageLoader.getImageListener(networkImageView,
            R.mipmap.ic_launcher, android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert));

    networkImageView.setImageUrl(word.getImg(), imageLoader);
    textViewen.setText(word.getEnglish());
    textViewar.setText(word.getArabic());
    textViewtag.setText(word.getTagoi());
    textViewaudio.setText(word.getAudio());

    return gridViewAndroid;
}
}
```

I hop to find more help
And thanks in advance

Comment: it is done 100% same way as with the ListView. You just need to spend more than a minute searching for the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is simple method to use search in grid list:

first make 2 List<>, one main and other for search purpose.

```
private List<Word> movieItems = new ArrayList<>();
private List<Word> movieItemsSearch = new ArrayList<>();
```

You must do add/clear/remove operations on both arrays.

Now use this code to filter data:

```
if (searchTerm.length() > 0) {
         movieItems.clear();
         for (Word s : movieItemsSearch) {
            String ss = s.getEnglish().toLowerCase();
            if (ss.contains(searchTerm.toLowerCase())) {
                movieItems.add(s);
            }
         }
         adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
} else {
         movieItems.clear();
         for (Word s : movieItemsSearch) {
              movieItems.add(s);
         }
         adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Here **searchTerm** is string value entered by user in search box.

Comment: in main activity

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to implement `Filterable` to your adapter. Please prefer to this tutorial for more information https://coderwall.com/p/zpwrsg/add-search-function-to-list-view-in-android.

Basically, on search, you can call this to filter your results after implementing `Filterable`

```
friendListAdapter.getFilter().filter(newText);
```